# I fail at installing PHP 5.6.1 in my MAMP PRO 3. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

I downloaded the package from the [MAMP website](http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/) and unzipped it into `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php` and rebooted MAMP PRO and I thought that should do it. Unfortunately it didn't work. I've tried searching with Google about this, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Can anybody enlighten me?

**edit** in case this is necessary, [here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjyqC.png)

Comment: Which OS are you on? `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php` looks like Mac, but I don't use one I can't tell. And if you are using Mac – isn't there a default packages manager containing those software?

Comment: Yes I am on a mac. And yes there are packet managers outside of MAMP, but I want MAMP to be able to use the latest php version so I need to install it inside of MAMP in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so eventually I fixed it doing this:
I completely reinstalled MAMP PRO and the new version had the latest php version already pre-installed. Luckily I didn't have to put in my serial key, because I have no idea what that was or where to find it. But then the extensions didn't work, because for some reason the php.ini pointed to the wrong folder. After I fixed that everything worked as expected.